# How to set selected option by using JavaScript or jQuery in data-bind select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**I bind-data in select option,**

```
<select 
  id="TanentNamesDB"
  data-bind="
  value:SelectedOrganisationData,
  event: { change: ConnectSelectedOrganization } ,
  options: GridAllOrganisationDataList,
  optionsText:'TenantName',optionsCaption: 'Choose your organisation ...',
  optionsId:'SelectTenantName'
   "
   class="dropdown">
 </select>
```

**It looks like this,**
[image]

**And, how to change the selected value using javascript or jquery, When I change the option manually it will automatically update to the database,**

I tried different, different way like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SelectOp = document.getElementById('TanentNamesDB');
    SelectOp.selectedOption(TanentNameSelected);

    $("#TanentNamesDB option[text='BD']").attr("selected", "selected");
    $("#TanentNamesDB").setSelectedOption("BD");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target an option containing some text and which is child of id `TanentNamesDB`, like this:

```js
$("#TanentNamesDB option:contains('BD')").prop("selected", true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="TanentNamesDB">
  <option disabled>Choose your organisation...</option>
  <option>BDML</option>
  <option>BD</option>
  <option>hSenid Au Solutions</option>
</select>
```